# Unable to start NFS server on Alpine Linux LXC

Tags: nfs, lxc, proxmox, alpine-linux

I'm trying to setup a NFS server on an Alpine Linux LXC running on Proxmox by following the instructions as outlined [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_nfs-server), but `rpc.statd` refuses to start. Here's an excerpt from `/var/log/messages` showing the error:

```
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.notice rpc.statd[226]: Version 2.1.1 starting
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.warn rpc.statd[226]: Flags: TI-RPC 
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.err rpc.statd[226]: Unable to prune capability 0 from bounding set: Operation not permitted
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.err /etc/init.d/rpc.statd[224]: start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/sbin/rpc.statd'
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.err /etc/init.d/rpc.statd[210]: ERROR: rpc.statd failed to start
Nov 26 03:08:25 nfs daemon.err /etc/init.d/nfs[228]: ERROR: cannot start nfs as rpc.statd would not start
```

I've created a custom apparmor profile for the LXC (found [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-run-a-nfs-server-within-a-lxc.24403/#post-150149)) to give the service enough permissions to run but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I needed the `CAP_SETPCAP` capability to run the NFS server.

This can be done by editing the container's configuration file in `/etc/pve/lxc/CTID.conf` (where `CTID` is your container ID) as follows:

```
....
# clear cap.drop
lxc.cap.drop:

# copy drop list from /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override sys_time sys_module sys_rawio

# copy drop list from /usr/share/lxc/config/alpine.common.conf with setpcap commented

lxc.cap.drop = audit_write
lxc.cap.drop = ipc_owner
lxc.cap.drop = mknod
# lxc.cap.drop = setpcap
lxc.cap.drop = sys_nice
lxc.cap.drop = sys_pacct
lxc.cap.drop = sys_ptrace
lxc.cap.drop = sys_rawio
lxc.cap.drop = sys_resource
lxc.cap.drop = sys_tty_config
lxc.cap.drop = syslog
lxc.cap.drop = wake_alarm
```

And voila!